# File not deleted from storage using file.delete()

Tags: java, android, file, uri, delete-file

I am using `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` to capture video and want to delete the media file thus created from storage. But am unable to do so.

MainActivity :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE=2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri videoUri = intent.getData();
            String path =getRealPathFromURI(videoUri);
            File file = new File(path);
            if(file.exists()) {
                Log.d("exist", "yes");
                boolean deleted = file.delete();
            }
            else
                Log.d("exist","no");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {// If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                
            } else {
                
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
            
        }
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

}
```

Manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.videorecorder">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.VideoRecorder">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The value returned by file.delete() is `false` and the file is not deleted from storage/gallery also.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: I wonder if you file is considered being used? And therefore you cant delete it.

Comment: There is no requirement for `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` to return a `Uri` that is from the `MediaStore`. Also, there is no requirement for entries in the `MediaStore` to have a `DATA` value that points to something on the filesystem that you can delete. [Use `EXTRA_OUTPUT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/MediaStore#action_video_capture) to request a particular output location that you control, so you know how to delete the resulting file.

Comment: `String path =getRealPathFromURI(videoUri)` Dont try to get a file system path for that nice uri. Bad habit. Just use the uri directly to delete the file.